# Error message when attempting to create a new Visual Studio Express 2012 Project

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I try to open any new project, I receive the error message:

"No exports were found that match the constraint: 
ContractName 
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.ITextDocumentFactoryService 
RequiredTypeIdentity 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.ITextDocumentFactoryService

Comment: You should have googled it before posting https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zxue/2015/01/02/fix-visual-studio-error-no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint/

Answer (score 0):

Just delete or rename this folder:
%AppData%..\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ComponentModelCache

[image]